# SQL syntax error using Python and psycopg

Tags: python, sql, sql-injection

**How can you fix this SQL-code?**

My Python code:

```
import os, pg, sys, re, psycopg2                                              

conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname=tk user=masi password=123")
cur = conn.cursor() 
cur.execute("""INSERT INTO courses ('course_nro')
    VALUES ( `:1` )""", ['hen'])
```

I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):                                            
  File "<stdin>", line 13, in <module>
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "'course_nro'"
LINE 1: INSERT INTO courses ('course_nro')
                             ^
```

Comment: did you tried with without quotes?

Comment: What do you think the `^` is pointing at? hehe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the quotes around the fieldname:

```
INSERT INTO courses (course_nro)
```

Comment: You also need to remove the backticks around the `:1` parameter.

Answer (score 2):

You made 3 different errors in the same query:

1. Field names should not be quoted.
2. psycopg2 uses tuples, not lists for arguments.
3. Positional arguments like ":1" are not supported.

Change your query into:

`cur.execute("""INSERT INTO courses (course_nro)
        VALUES (%s)""", ('hen',))`